# QProcess startDetached() not working in executable invoked from firefox

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, google-chrome, firefox

I have written a simple console app in Qt/C++ which on invocation executes an external application using:

```
QProcess::startDetached("myapp",args);
```

The console app is invoked by Chrome, Firefox and Opera using native messaging.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

Everything works fine on Mac, Windows and Linux except with the combination of

```
Firefox + Windows 10
```

The forking doesn't seem to work when firefox invokes the console app

```
QProcess::startDetached("myapp",args); // but same works for Chrome + Windows
```

And if I use

```
QProcess::execute("myapp",args);
```

it does work on firefox. But if user closes the firefox it closes `myapp` too as expected. So is their any way I can prevent `myapp` from exiting if firefox closes.